# Exactly 6 months for a transit visa from US to India via UK

Tags: visas, usa, uk, transit

Before you close this for being a potentially duplicate question, please understand that I have seen some of the questions and what I'm asking is a bit different.

As I understand, one would need a DATV if one won't be crossing border control in the UK. But the wording on their site is,

> You won’t need a visa if you: are traveling from Australia, Canada, New Zealand or the 
>   USA and it’s less than 6 months since you last entered that country with a valid entry visa

A relative of mine is traveling in 2 weeks time and will be leaving the US exactly 6 months after arrival. So while its not exactly less than 6 months, its not more either. It's exactly 6 months. Would my relative be required to apply for the DATV? He is a citizen of India.

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and clean up the question a little and add in some relevant detail, please feel free to rollback.

Comment: More then likely this is not going to work.  When you enter the country let's say on August 11th, 6 months will end on February 10th and given the direction of travel and flights which usually happen overnight from US to UK you will arrive on February 11th, which since the timezone differences aren't likely to be taken into account will put your relative entering the US just one day over the 6 months limit with all the consequences stemming from it.

Comment: @Karlson: Please write that as the answer. I will accept it. We figured as much as well :)

Comment: I can't write it as an answer since it's mostly supposition.

Comment: @Karlson: But it is correct :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, @Karlson is right! It has to be less than 6 months. Exactly 6 months or more is not an option and does not work out.

Quoting @Karlson:

> More then likely this is not going to work. When you enter the country
>   let's say on August 11th, 6 months will end on February 10th and given
>   the direction of travel and flights which usually happen overnight
>   from US to UK you will arrive on February 11th, which since the
>   timezone differences aren't likely to be taken into account will put
>   your relative entering the US just one day over the 6 months limit
>   with all the consequences stemming from it.

Comment: Comments tend to 'go away' over time. Could you please edit your own answer and add in his comment to it? You can quote him, if you wish to give attribution.